# PHP Static class has a very long name - can I use a shorter pointer?

Tags: php, constants, class-constants

I have a static class with a very long name, example:

```
class SomeClassWithAVeryLongName {
    const CONST_ONE = 'foo';
    const CONST_TWO = 'bar';
}
```

In my other class, I want to reference these constants. The problem is there are a bunch of them and I use them as associative keys so my code gets very verbose:

```
$someArray[SomeClassWithAVeryLongName::CONST_ONE][SomeClassWithAVeryLongName::CONST_TWO] = 'foobar';
```

Is there a way I can use a pointer of some kind? Something like:

```
// Pseudo code
$scwavln = 'SomeClassWithAVeryLongName';
$someArray[$scwavln::CONST_ONE][$scwavln::CONST_TWO] = 'foobar';
```

It doesn't seem to be working for me. I'm on PHP 5.2.6.

Comment: Code is much more often read than written. Consequently, you should try to write readable code. `$scwavln` is not readable, so don't do it.

Comment: Silly, that was just an example. The actual class name is `Facebook_Open_Graph_API` and I want to use `FBAPI`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class scwavln extends SomeClassWithAVeryLongName {}
$someArray[scwavln::CONST_ONE][scwavln::CONST_TWO] = 'foobar';
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, for the specific problem just assign the constant values to a shorter variable and use that as your index key.

```
$index1 = SomeClassWithAVeryLongName::CONST_ONE;
$index2 = SomeClassWithAVeryLongName::CONST_TWO;

$someArray[$index1][$index2] = 'foo';
```

---

However, you can do what you were attempting to do with PHP 5.3:

```
$Uri = '\\My\\Namespaced\\Class';

// you see the value of the const
var_dump($Uri::MY_CONST);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class SomeClassWithAVeryLongName {
    const CONST_ONE = 'foo';
    const CONST_TWO = 'bar';
}


$rfl = new ReflectionClass("SomeClassWithAVeryLongName");

$props = $rfl->getConstants();

print_r( $props );

Array
(
    [CONST_ONE] => foo
    [CONST_TWO] => bar
)
```

http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php